# Using C++, is there a way to detect whether floats/doubles denormals are being "normalized" by the compiler/system?

Tags: c++, compilation, floating-point, double, denormalization

Putting it directly, my question is precisely as stated in the title: in an application being written using C++, is there a way to detect whether floats/doubles denormals are being "normalized" by the compiler/system (e.g. trough DAZ, FTZ, etc)?

If context is needed, what I am trying to accomplish is to detect programaticaly the minimal float/double values. These results, however, depend on whether denormals are or not being "normalized": if they are, the minimal values are given by std's numeric limits min(), otherwise it's given by denorm_min().

Comment: As a test, perhaps you can set a var to denorm_min and then check whether it is equal to denorm_min or min?

Comment: @ShaunRamsey You mean assigning `x = denorm_min()` and then testing `if(x==denorm_min())` because if normalization is not being done, then x would stay equal to denorm_min, otherwise it would be forced to be equal min()?

Comment: I think @Nicol Bolas's answer is better. But yes that's the test I was preposing.

Comment: Also, doesn't denorm_min return min if has_denorm is denorm_absent?

Comment: @ShaunRamsey: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply trust the implementation to return [the correct values for `std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). If [`std::numeric_limits<float>::has_denorm` is `std::denorm_present`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_denorm), then you should assume that regular C++ operators will not implicitly normalize floating-point values.

Note that this is a separate query from [`std::numeric_limits<float>::has_iec559`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559), which tests for the usage of IEC-559/IEEE-754 floats. So a system can use IEEE-754 floats, but not support denormalized floats. Therefore, implementations which always flush denormalized floats to zero ought to return `std::denorm_absent` for `has_denorm`.

Comment: Thanks for the details! So, if I understood you correctly, "trusting the implementation" here would mean that I could do a simple test like 1) `x = std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()` and then 2) `if(x==1.17549435E-38f)`? Or, maybe even better, `if(std::numeric_limits<float>::min() == std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min())`?

Comment: @user2019840: What I mean by "trust the implementation" is to simply check `has_denorm`. If that value is `denorm_present`, then you should assume that it won't arbitrarily flush denormalized values.

Comment: Ah, got it, now I see what you mean. That's clever, because it's indeed a simple solution. Many thanks

Comment: I went with your more elegant solution and it works perfectly. But just for the sake of completeness, I tried what I commented before and it seems that `x = std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()` returns zero when flush-to-zero is enabled.